# Best way avoid eslint error on vue 3 input component which splits one value into two

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

please see the following code

```js
    <template>
      <input type="text" v-model="amount" />
      <select v-model="type">
        <option value="CR">Cr</option>
        <option value="DR">Dr</option>
      </select>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { computed } from "vue";
    
    export default {
      name: "balanceNew",
      props: ["modelValue"],
      setup(props, { emit }) {
        function setValue(amount, type) {
          let v = Number(amount);
          if (type === "CR") v = v * -1;
          emit("update:modelValue", v);
        }
    
        const amount = computed({
          get() {
            return Math.abs(Number(props.modelValue));
          },
          set(v) {
            setValue(v, type.value);
          },
        });
    
        const type = computed({
          get() {
            if (Number(props.modelValue) < 0) return "CR";
            return "DR";
          },
          set(v) {
            setValue(amount.value, v);
          },
        });
    
        return { amount, type };
      },
    };
    </script>
```

In this component two values are taken as input as emitted another calculated value as output.
Now the above code works if eslint is disabled, else it shows `'type' is not defined` in setter of amount.

I tried multiple combinations of same procedure, even with ref and watcher but nothing seems working(without adding too much complexity) or elegant as the above code.

It was simpler in vue 2 options api which uses `this`, (and yes I know I can use the options api in vue 3, but other logic is in composition api and I don't like to add options api just for this.)

So anyone has any alternative method which works the same (and easy to understand) without disabling eslint ? (not even for single line)

---

## Update

though the accepted answer works exactly as I wanted, but more alternative ways are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting them in an object could solve this issue, if you like:

```js
export default {
  name: "balanceNew",

  props: ["modelValue"],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    function setValue(amount, type) {
      let v = Number(amount);
      if (type === "CR") v = v * -1;
      emit("update:modelValue", v);
    }

    const store = {
      amount: computed({
        get() {
          return Math.abs(Number(props.modelValue));
        },
        set(v) {
          setValue(v, store.type.value);
        }
      }),

      type: computed({
        get() {
          if (Number(props.modelValue) < 0) return "CR";
          return "DR";
        },
        set(v) {
          setValue(store.amount.value, v);
        }
      })
    }

    return { ...store };
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I asked. will mark as accepted after testing. Thanks!